# sql query with view

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following database schema :

[image: schema]
High resolution image is here http://s18.postimage.org/mlyw5gea1/schema2.png

As you can see :

a speaker is associated with a session directly.

a section is associated with a session directly.

a speaker is indirectly associated with a section through the speakerFunction, then the secion_speakerfunction-join-table until the section.

How to get all speakers where there indirect sessions is not one of there direct sessions

Any help is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: I am doing this on my phone so can't provide an example, but have you tried a acquire sub  query?  E.g select * from speaker where id not in (select id from speaker-associated-sections)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After refreshing my memory by reading [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) and this clear article on [net.tutsplus](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships/) and some hair pulling I was able to lay a query that works.

```
select * from speaker as spk
inner join speakerFunction as spkfun
    on (spkfun.speaker_id = spk.id)
inner join section_speakerfunction-join-table as s_spkfun
    on (s_spkfun.speakerFunction_id = spkfun.id)
inner join section as s
    on (s.id = s_spkfun.section_id)
inner join session as sess1
    on (sess1.id = s.session_id)
left join session-speaker-join-table as sess-spk
    on (sess-spk.speaker_id = spk.id)
left join session as sess2
    on (sess2.id = sess-spk.session_id)
where sess-spk.session_id is null
```

As you can see a lot of inner join and then a left outer join to be able to filter (where clause) on null session_id.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I cannot zoom your graphic, so the following involved a bit of guesswork.

As you've already stated, there are two ways to get from any given session to the relating speakers. First, you can get a list of speakers directly associated with the session:

```
SELECT speaker.* FROM `session-speaker-join-table`
JOIN speaker 
  ON speaker.id=`session-speaker-join-table`.speaker_id
WHERE `session-speaker-join-table`.session_id=1234
```

And here's how to get the list of speakers indirectly linked through speakerfunction:

```
SELECT speaker.* FROM section
JOIN `section-speakerfunction-join-table` 
  ON `section-speakerfunction-join-table`.section_id=section.id
JOIN speakerfunction 
  ON speakerfunction.id=`section-speakerfunction-join-table`.speakerfunction_id
JOIN speaker 
  ON speaker.id=speakerfunction.speaker_id
WHERE section.session_id=1234
```

Edit: After reading your comment I understand you want the result of query 2 minus the results of query 1. That can be accomplished by adding a `LEFT JOIN` to the second query and then checking if there is no match, like this:

```
SELECT speaker.* FROM section
JOIN `section-speakerfunction-join-table` 
  ON `section-speakerfunction-join-table`.section_id=section.id
JOIN speakerfunction 
  ON speakerfunction.id=`section-speakerfunction-join-table`.speakerfunction_id
JOIN speaker 
  ON speakerfunction.speaker_id = speaker.id
LEFT JOIN `session-speaker-join-table` 
  ON `session-speaker-join-table`.session_id=section.session_id 
 AND `session-speaker-join-table`.speaker_id=speaker.speaker_id
WHERE section.session_id=1234 AND `session-speaker-join-table`.speaker_id IS NULL
```

(I also changed the table names and included backticks, I hope I caught them all. Also reformatted the queries for better readability.)

Comment: Thanks, I added high resolution image. What I want is all speakers where there indirect "session" is not one of there direct session

Comment: You should not be using a where clause on section.session_id=1234.I tried also by removing it from the where clause leaving the `session-speaker-join-table`.speaker_id IS NULL alone but it didn't work. Anyway, see my response with the solution and thanks a lot for you much appreciated help.

Comment: I put the where clause in there as to your request: "I want to understand how to get all speakers associated with a session", the number 1234 was meant as placeholder for the id of the seesion you were looking for.